# How to make the changes from one commit to another branch using PyGithub?

Tags: python, pygithub

I have a repo where I have two branches:
master and
master_one.
I have one commit (commit1) in master branch that is not present in master_one.
Now I have created one more branch 'temp' from master_one.
I wanted to merge the changes present in commit1 to my branch temp using PyGithub.
I am able to merge it if I am creating a branch from master using the below code:

```
repo.merge(branch_name,commit_sha_key,"merge to master")
```

where `commit_sha_key` is the sha of commit1.

But same thing I am not able to do for my temp branch that I have created from master_one.

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: It is not merging the changes of commit1 in temp branch.

Comment: Does it fail silently or with an error?

Comment: It is not failing I am not seeing any error but after the code get executed I am not seeing any commit in temp branch.

Comment: And if you print the output?

Comment: Actually I am getting this time out error:- HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.abc.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)

Comment: Are you using regular, public GitHub? If so, what is github.abc.com?

Comment: I am using github enterprise. In github.abc.com, abc is enterprise name.

Comment: And you don’t get the timeout for the master branch?

Comment: no for the branch created from master, I am not getting this.

Comment: What happens if you try cURLing the api directly?

Comment: Is is something because commit1 is present in master so when I create some branch from master itself it is having all the previous commits before commit1 already present there. So it is only merging the the changes present in commit1.
But for temp branch which is created from master-one, it is trying to merge all the commits present in master so getting timedout?

Comment: @Ezra, I am not getting how to use cURLing directly?

Comment: yes that’s my theory (if I understand you correctly). Direct api reference, with curl instructions: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#merging

Comment: If I am using git cherry-pick <commit hash> from command line, I am able to merge commit1 in temp branch. Is there something that I can do with PyGitHub?

Comment: I found here https://github.community/t/do-a-cherry-pick-via-the-api/14573 there is no direct github api for cherry pick. The functionality has latest been added in github desktop only. Is there any other way? I am right now stuck at this point.

Comment: Can someone suggest me any way to achieve it? It will be very helpful.

Comment: see my answer. You can’t do it from pygithub, but that doesn’t mean you can’t do it (or that it’s hard)

Answer (score 0):

Cherry pick isn’t supported by the GitHub api, so you’ll have to do it from the command line:

```py
# ~~~ snip initialize git repo locally, maybe using git clone  ~~~
import os
os.system(f"git cherry-pick {commit_sha_key}")
os.system("git push")  # you may need to do "git push origin temp"
# ~~~ snip ~~~ cleanup, if you want.
```

Comment: I have tried it but I don't want to clone the repo locally as it is a large repo and can take time.

Comment: You could try a shallow clone.